# What does "Fight through the pain" mean?

Tags: phrases, idioms, sentence

What does sentence "Fight through the pain" mean? I heard this sentence in XBox360 game Gears of War. Can the sentence be also used with other verbs - can it be simply expressed as pattern "Do something through the pain"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phrases starting with "Fight through the/it", are telling the subject to stay strong and bear whatever trouble or pain they are enduring.

*Fight through the pain* - means to struggle onward with whatever is being suffered, *despite the pain*.

You can use other words than pain for other difficulties.  Occasionally it can be seen with the word *bureaucracy*, to mean getting past all the obstacles that an infrastructure, forms and procedure put in the way of a goal.

Comment: So the "pain" part can be occassionally replaced but replacing "Fight" part will completely break the meaning? For example saying "Learn something through the pain" is not correct?

Comment: @Ladislav Generally the verb that replaces fight would be an action verb such as "play" or "work" or "run".

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: It is possible to replace the verb, providing the switch is to something that would make sense in that context.  "Learn through the pain" sort of works, though usually it is only replaced with a small set of action words, *work* being one of the more common replacements.  Generally though, the phrase is always *fight through the pain*.